# Missing sudo Password - Ansible on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible, terraform, passwords, devops

first time here!

So, Im trying to execute a playbook from my local machine to a Google Cloud Platform VM. Im authenticated with a service account that has Owner role. I have `become:yes` on my main.yml file.

On this task:

```
-
  name: "Configure database application"
  shell: "{{item}}"
  become: yes
  args:
    chdir: "/var/lib/usr/tool-anotacao/backend/releases/{{tool_backend_version}}"
  with_items:
    - "php72 bin/console doctrine:schema:drop --force"
    - "php72 bin/console doctrine:schema:create"
```

it returns:

```
fatal: [xx.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Missing sudo password"}
```

I don't know whats missing, how can i get this sudo password from a VM that i provisioned with Terraform?

Here are my config files:

main.yml:

```
---
- name: Setting up Application!
  hosts: flow
  become: yes
  roles:
    - role1
    - role2
    - role3
```

inventory.gcp.yml:

```
plugin: gcp_compute
projects:
  - my-project
auth_kind: serviceaccount
service_account_file: /home/my-credentials
keyed_groups:
  - key: labels
    prefix: label
  - key: zone
    prefix: zone
groups:
  flow: "'flow' in (labels|list)"
```

ansible.cfg

```
[inventory]
enable_plugins = gcp_compute

[defaults]
remote_user = <my-service-account-user>
timeout=60
host_key_checking = False
deprecation_warnings=False
inventory = /inventory.gcp.yml
become_ask_pass = True
```

Comment: On Google Compute Engine, password-based authentication is disabled. I do use Ansible, but you probably need to run Ansible with elevated permissions (sudo).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make your my-service-account-user sudoer without password on the remote gcp machine

Comment: But how? i mean, yes this might work for this specific machine, but, the goal is to get this whole process automated, so when i provision a machine with terraform, ansible can work on this machine.  If i do that, i will have to do this process with every machine?

Comment: If you don't want to change the machines (which is "automatable") you can pass the option "-K" to your ansible command so that it ask YOU for the sudo password.